# Recent MySql Cluster Improvements

Tags: mysql

I've recently been reading around the internet about scalability of MySql among other various databases. One thing I have noticed about MySql Cluster is that many of the questions and blogs about it are severely outdated, coming on 3-4 years of age. I wanted to get a more recent perspective with the release of MySql Cluster 7.2 GA. Some general concerns I have are stability, compound keys, data loss, and network communication among data nodes, since if I decide to use it, I will be hosting with AWS EC2. Does anyone have any recent experience with MySql Cluster and can provide some enlightenment? Thanks.

Comment: I think this should go on serverfault. As I understand now it get's much better if we are talking about scalability/replication. For example: https://kb.askmonty.org/en/galera/ http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster but I really don't know how stable this stuff is

Comment: There's also a Stack Overflow for [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com) questions.

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure - I work on the MySQL Cluster product team

I can drone on for hours about MySQL Cluster evolution and improvements (!), but it would be better to hear directly from users.

PayPal implemented their global fraud detection system on MySQL Cluster 7.2 - deployed across 5 x AWS regions, protecting over $100bn of transactions.  There is press coverage and a keynote video here:
http://www.mysql.com/customers/view/?id=1223

PlayFul Play - developer of largest social game in Latin America have deployed on MySQL Cluster 7.2, running on SoftLayer cloud:
https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/mysql_cluster_powers_el_chavo

So, you won't be surprised if I advise to go ahead and try it!

Comment: After reading around blogs and such, I noticed that there is 48 data node limit. Why is that? What happens after you hit that limit? Is it vertical scaling from there?